# Дискорд бот на python, упоминание ролей

Tags: python, discord.py

Подскажите, как упомянуть роль через бота в дискорде?

```
await message.channel.send("@admin")
```

Вот такой код не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Способ:**

Что бы упомянуть роль достаточно знать её ID и отправить сообщение с таким содержанием:

```
await message.channel.send("<@&id_роли>")
```

**2. Способ:**

Получить роль и упомянуть её:

```
from discord.ext import commands


@commands.command()
async def push(ctx: commands.Context):
    # Получаем роль
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id=id_роли)
    # Отправляем сообщение
    await ctx.send(f"Роль: {role.mention}")
```

Если у вас уже имеется ID, то смысла получать роль нет, если в дальнейшем вы ничего не будете с ней делать.